# How to remove border in radial gradient so that it can mix well?

Tags: html, css, web

I have radial gradient as below :

[image]

How to remove the final dark border so that it mix with background ?

( Wrinkles are okay, But final border line is annoying )

Basically I am trying to have a glow element in middle of plain background.
Any alternative is also welcome :)

**CSS**

```
#rectangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: #112d44;
}
#rectangle:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom : 0%;
  right: 0;
  left: -10%;
  width:1680px;
  height: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgb(17, 67, 96) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="rectangle" ></div>
```

Pen can be found here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNOLGx Please fork first.

Comment: I think it looks smooth if you use more colors: background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #E4F0FB 10%, #112D44 25%, #112D44 30%, #112D44 10%, transparent 40%);
}

Comment: I think it is better with closest-side: background:radial-gradient(ellipse closest-side, #E4F0FB 10%, #112D44 25%, #112D44 30%, #112D44 10%, transparent 40%);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your gradient fade to the background colour, and hide any overflow so that your `::after` pseudo element doesn't break out of its container:

```
#rectangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: #112d44;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rectangle:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  bottom : 0%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0%;
  width:1680px;
  height: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgb(17, 67, 96) 0%, rgb(17, 45, 68) 50%);
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MawKOM)

Comment: But Still It is not mixed. Border is clearly visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks smooth if you use more colors, transparency and 'closest-side':

```
background:radial-gradient(ellipse closest-side, 
rgba(35, 80, 117, 0.27) 10%, 
rgba(25, 61, 90, 0.46) 25%, 
rgba(17, 45, 68, 0.66) 30%, 
rgba(17, 45, 68, 0.85) 10%, 
transparent 40%)
```

I hope it is what you need.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOdZxY